# Simple mysql selection

Tags: php, mysql

What im trying to do is checking if a value exists in the table.If it does not exist a sorry message should be displayed.The code is posted below even though the value exists it always return sorry

```
if ($mysqli->query("SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `k1`='$string1' AND 'k2'='$string2'"))
    {

    if($mysqli->affected_rows==0)
    {
    printf("Sorry");
    }
    }
```

Comment: affected_rows works only with DELETE, INSERT and UPDATE

Comment: Also, `'$$string2'"))`, is that correct? Have you accidently doubled up the `$`?

Comment: @webnoob sorry for that edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use

```
 $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `k1`='$string1' AND 'k2'='$$string2'");
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `k1`='$string1' AND 'k2'='$$string2'"))
        {

        if($result->num_rows==0)
        {
        printf("Sorry");
        }
        }
```

As you are making query as SELECT statement.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check for the number of rows and not the number of affected rows:

```
if ($result->num_rows == 0)
{
    echo 'sorry';
}
```

affected_rows is for insert, update and delete statements where you want to know how many rows were affected by the statement.

num_rows return the number or rows returned by a select statement

Comment: Tried it but getting this error Undefined property: mysqli::$num_rows

Comment: This code is fine, it just represents the bit that was wrong in your code, not the code in it's entirety.

Comment: how can the mysqli have num_rows property?